# Non significant A/B test, what is the future expected value?

Tags: expected-value, ab-test

Suppose you run an A/B test with a result that is not significant. For example:

```
Version A:
10,000 views, 100 clicks

Version B:
10,000 views, 115 clicks
```

What is the expected number of clicks if you increase version B to 100,000 views?

It seems obvious to me that it should be 1150, but I don't know if I can either prove or disprove this?

Comment: Your "obvious" projection appears to contradict your assertion that you view the difference between A and B as "not significant."  What, then, do you mean by "not significant"?